# What's a constructor real application in c++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I can initialize a member variable from a class for example with a constructor, of course but i can also do this by creating a variable of type class from which i could use it's members and initialize them by doing a function. So, i would like to know if the use of a constructor has something to do with reducing memory usage or real time enhancement that makes application more responsive.

Here i placed an example that i found on the internet. Trying to understand the real usage of a constructor in a c program as well in real life.

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 class Line
{
   public:
      void setLength( double len );
      double getLength( void );
      Line(); 

   private:
      double length;
};
 Line::Line(void)
{
    cout << "Object is being created" << endl;
}
 void Line::setLength( double len )
{
    length = len;
}
 double Line::getLength( void )
{
    return length;
}
int main( )
{
   Line line;


   line.setLength(6.0); 
   cout << "Length of line : " << line.getLength() <<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason is that is reduces the scope for errors. Allowing an object to be constructed in an invalid/nonsensical state means it can be used in that state.

```
Line line;

// any read line.length is undefined behaviour
// What is the benefit of that?

line.setLength(6.0);
```

Constructors allow you to initialize instances in a valid and desired state, which means they can be used immediately without further manipulations.

Also, in regarding terminology, `line.setLength(6.0)` does not *initialize* the member, it modifies an already initialized one.

Comment: And it also has something to do with memory? or not? my confusion is that i could do this without having to use a constructor but i was thinking it may reduce memory consumption and that's why is useful but as you said it reduces the scope for errors as well

Comment: @MarioPineda No, but if you have data members whose default initialization is expensive, default initializing and then modifying can be more expensive than just initializing to the desired values. In any case, why do two things when you can achieve the same with one?

Answer (score 2):

In real life, in larger nontrivial projects, you forget to call your own initializers, leaving the object in uninitialized state. But you can't forget to call a constructor.

Comment: Very importante fact!

Answer (score 2):

A constructor provides a syntax that *can guarantee that your object is completely initialized* when it is created.

Bugs abound when you create an object that requires additional function calls before it's not in an uninitialized state.

Comment: Note that a constructor doesn't guarantee complete initialization.

Comment: @DrewDormann with "Bugs abound when you create an object that requires additional function calls before it's not in an uninitialized state" you mean making those function calls when the object is in an uninitialized state?

Answer (score 1):

There are reasons to favor a constructor over a method, and often, these reasons depend on the context. Let's first consider the most obvious reason to favor constructors: immutable objects. An object that's considered to be immutable will never change its state after its initial construction (where it's declared and constructed). Often, such immutable objects keep their member variables private and allow you to create other instances of them based on various functions (e.g., a string's `substring` routine).

On the other hand, objects which go through various state changes throughout their life (e.g., a GameBoard) may require client calls to modify their state. However, even these objects will be initialized somehow (e.g., think Chess, Checkers, Sudoko, etc...) and should require a basic constructor to ensure that they started from a "sane" initial state.

Methods *can* initialize objects, but only sometimes is this legal. For instance a member variable that is a reference must be initialized in the constructor list, variables that require parameters, variables that are const, etc...

From a performance perspective, I don't know how I would resolve this aspect of the question... but writing clean and clear code always makes other programmers reading your code efficient and, dare-i-say-it, happy! :-)

Comment: Excelent! Response! Thank you!